# Socketpair is only printing the first line from stdin

Tags: c, sockets, fork, toupper

I am doing a simple project in C involving `fork()` and `socketpairs`. The program forks a process then creates a socketpair for the processes to talk to one another. The parent process reads lines from stdin one at a time until EOF, and then sends the lines one by one the the child. The child converts the lines to uppercase and sends them back to the parent, who sends them to stdout. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  /* code */
  int returnCode, status, socket[2], j;
  char* buffer;
  size_t bufferSize = 100;
  size_t line;

  buffer = (char *)malloc(bufferSize * sizeof(char));
  socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket);

  returnCode = fork();
  if(returnCode == -1){
    printf("Fork failed\n");
  }
  if(returnCode > 0){
    while(getline(&buffer, &bufferSize, stdin) != -1){
      write(socket[1], buffer, bufferSize);
      read(socket[1], buffer, bufferSize);
      printf("%s", buffer);
    }
  }
  else{
    read (socket[0], buffer, bufferSize);
    for(j = 0; j[buffer];j++){
      buffer[j] = toupper(buffer[j]);
    }
    write(socket[0], buffer, bufferSize);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My program prints the first line from stdin capitalized, but then it hangs. I have to ctrl-c to exit. How do i get the sockets to loop thru until EOF printing the modified lines?

Comment: pretty sure the newline gets left on the end of stdin and it keeps getting read over and over as a terminator for the line.   You have to do some sort of ignore command on it or something.  It's a pretty common question.  Search for "stdin newline ignore" without the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My program prints the first line from stdin capitalized, but then it
>   hangs. I have to ctrl-c to exit. How do i get the sockets to loop thru
>   until EOF printing the modified lines?

Your child process's routine (i.e. the one that does the toupper() calls) only calls read() one time, and then calls write() one time, and then exits.  That is why only one line is processed.  To get it to do multiple lines, you'd need to put the code into a loop:

```
[...]
  else{
    while(read(socket[0], buffer, bufferSize) > 0)
    {
       for(j = 0; j[buffer];j++){
         buffer[j] = toupper(buffer[j]);
       }
       write(socket[0], buffer, bufferSize);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Oversight on my part